# JainSip on Android: Sending REGISTER throws Exception

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sip, jain-sip

during the last days I tried to get JAIN SIP working on Android. I took some code that works fine on a Java Application and ported it to an Android Application.

I checked:

- Permissions in the Manifest (INTERNET / ALL)
- JAIN SIP API works fine (other threads on stackoverflow focus that).
- Communication runs on an own Thread, not the MainThread.
- IPs are valid.
- The code works if I'm not using Android as platform but Ubuntu.
- I tried Android 4.0.3 and above.

---

My Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SipListener {

private static final String LOG = "JAIN";
private static final int PORT = 5060;
private SipFactory mSipFactory;
private AddressFactory mAddressFactory;
private MessageFactory mMessageFacory;
private HeaderFactory mHeaderFactory;
private SipStack mSipStack;
private SipProvider mSipProvider;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    new Thread(new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                // Create factories
                mSipFactory = SipFactory.getInstance();
                mAddressFactory = mSipFactory.createAddressFactory();
                mMessageFacory = mSipFactory.createMessageFactory();
                mHeaderFactory = mSipFactory.createHeaderFactory();

                // Create the SipStack
                Properties properties = new Properties();
                properties.setProperty("javax.sip.STACK_NAME","Stack");
                mSipStack = mSipFactory.createSipStack(properties);

                // Create the SipProvider 
                String localIP = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();
                ListeningPoint listeningPoint = mSipStack
                        .createListeningPoint(localIP, PORT, "udp");
                mSipProvider = mSipStack.createSipProvider(listeningPoint);
                mSipProvider.addSipListener(MainActivity.this);

                // Create addresses and via header for the request
                Address fromToAddress = mAddressFactory
                        .createAddress("sip:192.168.0.198");
                Address contactAddress = mAddressFactory
                        .createAddress("sip:me@192.168.0.195");
                ArrayList<ViaHeader> viaHeaders = new ArrayList<ViaHeader>();
                ViaHeader myViaHeader = mHeaderFactory
                        .createViaHeader("me.bla.com", PORT, "udp", "tlf64");
                viaHeaders.add(myViaHeader);

                // Build the request
                final Request request = mMessageFacory.createRequest(
                        mAddressFactory.createAddress("sip:192.168.0.195:9876").getURI(), 
                        "REGISTER",
                        mHeaderFactory.createCallIdHeader("12345678"),
                        mHeaderFactory.createCSeqHeader(1234l, "REGISTER"), 
                        mHeaderFactory.createFromHeader(fromToAddress, "sdf6"),
                        mHeaderFactory.createToHeader(fromToAddress, null), 
                        viaHeaders, 
                        mHeaderFactory.createMaxForwardsHeader(70));

                // Add the contact header
                request.addHeader(mHeaderFactory.createContactHeader(contactAddress));

                // Print the request
                System.out.println(request.toString());

                // Send the request --- triggers an IOException
                mSipProvider.sendRequest(request);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d(LOG, Log.getStackTraceString(e));
            }
        }}).start();
}
```

---

As you can see in the StackTrace, an IOException occurs:

```
javax.sip.SipException: IO Exception occured while Sending Request
at gov.nist.javax.sip.SipProviderImpl.sendRequest(SipProviderImpl.java:722)
at com.example.jainsiptest.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:97)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
 Caused by: java.net.SocketException: sendto failed: EINVAL (Invalid argument)
at libcore.io.IoBridge.maybeThrowAfterSendto(IoBridge.java:506)
at libcore.io.IoBridge.sendto(IoBridge.java:475)
at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.send(PlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:182)
at java.net.DatagramSocket.send(DatagramSocket.java:284)
at gov.nist.javax.sip.stack.UDPMessageChannel.sendMessage(UDPMessageChannel.java:724)
at gov.nist.javax.sip.stack.MessageChannel.sendMessage(MessageChannel.java:222)
at gov.nist.javax.sip.SipProviderImpl.sendRequest(SipProviderImpl.java:711)
... 2 more
 Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: sendto failed: EINVAL (Invalid argument)
at libcore.io.Posix.sendtoBytes(Native Method)
at libcore.io.Posix.sendto(Posix.java:151)
at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.sendto(BlockGuardOs.java:177)
at libcore.io.IoBridge.sendto(IoBridge.java:473)
... 7 more
```

---

The

```
java.net.SocketException: sendto failed: EINVAL (Invalid argument)
```

is not thrown on Ubuntu with the same arguments.

Got any ideas how to fix it? Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5042548/sending-udp-packages-from-android-2-2-htc-desire

Comment: Not related. There is a different problem due to invalid IPs. My IPs are valid as MjSip shows. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the Android OS processes the given Strings in a different way than the Ubuntu OS. I don't know why.

---

After all, I fixed the problem by using MjSip instead of JAIN SIP.

Since I need RTP, SDP and some more stuff next to SIP, I decided to modify the open source Android App [Sipdroid](http://code.google.com/p/sipdroid/), which uses MjSip 1.6, until it fits my demands.

1. To do so, first get the [code](http://code.google.com/p/sipdroid/source/checkout).
2. Import the project into Eclipse: File -> Import -> Existing Android Code Into Workspace.
3. Create a new Android project that meets your demands considering API Level and so on.
4. Add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` to the Manifest of your project.
5. Copy all packages but the following from the Sipdroid project to your project:

   - org.sipdroid.codecs and org.sipdroid.media (which I don't need yet, maybe later)
   - org.sipdroid.sipua and subpackages.
6. Delete or comment broken references.
7. See the code below to send a REGISTER to a server.
8. Fix the Exeptions that are thrown by the Log mechanism by using `android.util.Log` instead of the given code. Finally, delete or comment the flush command that triggers a NullPointerException.

That's it.

```
import org.zoolu.sip.address.NameAddress;
import org.zoolu.sip.message.Message;
import org.zoolu.sip.message.MessageFactory;
import org.zoolu.sip.provider.SipProvider;
import org.zoolu.sip.provider.SipStack;
import org.zoolu.sip.transaction.TransactionClient;
import org.zoolu.sip.transaction.TransactionClientListener;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements TransactionClientListener{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    new Thread(new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try{
                SipStack.init();

                SipProvider sipProvider = new SipProvider(
                        "192.168.0.198", 5060, new String[]{"udp"}, null);
                NameAddress toAddress = new NameAddress(
                        "sip:192.168.0.195:9876");
                NameAddress fromAddress = new NameAddress(
                        "sip:192.168.0.198:9876");

                Message message = MessageFactory.createRegisterRequest(
                        sipProvider, 
                        toAddress, 
                        fromAddress, 
                        fromAddress, 
                        null, 
                        null);

                TransactionClient t = new TransactionClient(
                        sipProvider, 
                        message,
                        MainActivity.this);

                t.request();

            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("MYSIP", Log.getStackTraceString(e));
            }
        }}).start();
}

// Interface methods

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of fetching `localIPAddress` as:

```
String localIP = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();
```

Fetch the IP Address using `NetworkInterface` or `WifiManager`.